# What can a hacker do using my SSL certificate and key

Tags: security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

If I gave my SSL certificate & private key being used on website mydomain[dot]com to some hacker, would the hacker be able to hijack / intercept the connection or misuse in any way?

Comment: Private Key ?  Dont do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so basically, *"What's the point of protecting an SSL certificate's private key?"*

The proper name for the attack you're describing is "[Man in the Middle (MitM) attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)".

As the name implies, the attacker needs to be in the middle [[source article for the image](https://medium.com/@anglee19/man-in-the-middle-and-arp-spoofing-d579a33e58bf)]:

[image: Man in the middle attack diagram]

At this point, you will open an HTTPS connection to the attacker and because they have the certificate and private key, you can't tell that you are not talking directly to the legitimate web site. The attacker then opens another HTTPS connection between themselves and the server; because they are re-transmitting your messages (including your login) the server can't tell that they are not talking directly to you. The attacker is "in the middle".

How does the attacker get in the middle? Maybe they are on the same hosting service as you and have somehow tricked the service provider to route your traffic to them. Maybe they are one of the legitimate routers on the internet. Maybe they have used techniques such as [BGP Hacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP_hijacking) to convince the legitimate routers that they have a fast route to your server. Maybe they are in the same wifi is the victim and have used [ARP Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) to convince the victim that their laptop is the wifi router and all traffic should go through it. Lots of ways, all of which require "an extra step" in order to perform the attack.

---

**Summary:** An attacker with your SSL certificate and private key can't do anything directly, but it opens up a whole category of attacks if they also have the ability to manipulate network traffic to put themselves "in between" your site and the victim.